# How to add html to title output of taxonomy terms in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

I just cant figure it out. How can change the title output of a term?
I have a content type which displays the selected terms. The term is displayed as a link. How can I change this:

```
<div class="field-item even">
    <a href="/category/fe-sub">FE-Sub</a>
</div>
```

to something like this:

```
<div class="field-item even">
    <a href="/category/fe-sub">
        <strong>FE-Sub</strong>
    </a>
</div>
```

Edit: I tried it out with `mymodule_preprocess_field(&$variables)` but you may not enter html, it will print "-Element

```
function proposals_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if (isset($variables) && isset($variables['items']['0']['#options']['entity_type']) && $variables['items']['0']['#options']['entity_type'] == 'taxonomy_term') {
        $variables['items']['0']['#title'] = '<b>'.$variables['items']['0']['#title'].'</b>';
    }
}
```

renders link text:

`<strong>term title</strong>` instead of **term title**

**EDIT:** here is how i made it work:
in your template.php:

```
function yourtheme_field__taxonomy_term_reference($variables) {
  $output = '';

  // Render the label, if it's not hidden.
  if (!$variables['label_hidden']) {
    $output .= '<h3 class="field-label">' . $variables['label'] . ': </h3>';
  }

  // Render the items.
  $output .= ($variables['element']['#label_display'] == 'inline') ? '<ul class="links inline">' : '<ul class="links">';

  foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    // allow html
    $item['#options']['html'] = TRUE;
    // set html
    $item['#title'] = '<span class="label label-info">'.$item['#title'].'</span>';

    $output .= '<li class="taxonomy-term-reference-' . $delta . '"' . $variables['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . drupal_render($item) . '</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  // Render the top-level DIV.
  $output = '<div class="' . $variables['classes'] . (!in_array('clearfix', $variables['classes_array']) ? ' clearfix' : '') . '"' . $variables['attributes'] .'>' . $output . '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make changes to the taxonomy term out put you can use the below function. This is taken from the batrik theme so you would use the function `mytheme_field__taxonomy_term_reference`

To change the markup of the term change #markup the defualt value would be

```
<a href="/drupal7/class/class-1" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel">term name</a>
```

change that to

```
 $item[#markup] = '<a href="/drupal7/class/class-1" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel"><strong>term name</strong></a>'

function batrik_field__taxonomy_term_reference($variables) {
  $output = '';

  // Render the label, if it's not hidden.
  if (!$variables['label_hidden']) {
    $output .= '<h3 class="field-label">' . $variables['label'] . ': </h3>';
  }

  // Render the items.
  $output .= ($variables['element']['#label_display'] == 'inline') ? '<ul class="links inline">' : '<ul class="links">';
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $output .= '<li class="taxonomy-term-reference-' . $delta . '"' . $variables['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . drupal_render($item) . '</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  // Render the top-level DIV.
  $output = '<div class="' . $variables['classes'] . (!in_array('clearfix', $variables['classes_array']) ? ' clearfix' : '') . '"' . $variables['attributes'] .'>' . $output . '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: I am not using it with views

Comment: Where do you want to change it? in the node or taxonomy page?

Comment: On the node.
Even when using views I can only seem to change the wrapper html, not the html inside the <a> since there is no replacement pattern like "term url"

Comment: with in view you dont have to use any replacement. just do what I mentioned in the answer. I am getting the info for the other query.

Comment: no, i am afraid you are wrong. "customize field html" does get wrapped around the title, but not if the term is being formatted as a link. then the "customize field html" element is being wrapped around the <a> tag, not the title directly.

Comment: mm I guess I got that one wrong. when I checked it again you are right it does gets wrapped around the a tag and not the title itself sorry about that. Please check the function I mentioned that would do what you want.

Comment: no problem :) well, the function does work but i am on my original problem again:  
$item['#title'] = '<span class="label label-info">'.$item['#title'].'</span>';  
prints "<span>" instead of rendering an actualy span

Comment: THANK GOD i made it:
$item['#options']['html'] = TRUE;
    $item['#title'] = '<span class="label label-info">'.$item['#title'].'</span>';

Comment: you could also change the #markup you want.